# Longest common substring between two sequences with minimum error correction

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have two strings A and B. I want to find the longest common substring between these two strings while allowing minimum error correction in B or A. The errors are in the form of adjacent swaps, for example `s_1s_2...s_i s_{i+1}...s_n` is one swap away from the string `s_1s_2...s_{i+1} s_{i}...s_n`. Is there any dynamic programming solution for it?

The score for matching a letter in two strings is M and the penalty for swapping is P. So in total the objective is maximizing the total M - P. Obviously If I swap two adjacent letters in A and there is a matched in B for these letters, then the score will increase by 2M - P.

I have written a recursive code for calculating the LCS but I don't know how to add the swap correction.

```
M = 1 # score for matching a letter in two strings
P = 1 # penalty for swapping

def lcs(A, B, i, j, res):
    if i == -1 or j == -1:
        return res
    if A[i] == B[j]:
        res = lcs(A, B, i - 1, j - 1, res + M)
    return max(res, max(lcs(A, B, i, j - 1, 0), lcs(A, B, i - 1, j, 0)))


>>> A = "fghijklmnopq"
>>> B = "klmnopqrstuv"
>>> res = lcs(A, B, len(A) - 1, len(B) - 1, 0)
>>> print(res)
7
```

Comment: You have stated two quantities you want to optimise - the length of the substring, and the number of swaps. For an optimisation problem to be well-defined you need to specify just one definition of what it means for a solution to be optimal. Are you trying to maximise the substring length minus the number of swaps, for example?

Comment: Search for "edit distance" and "longest common sub sequence". That should give you plenty of examples.

Comment: @kaya3, yes exactly. I edited the question and give them a score M and penalty P.